# C unsigned char unexpected behavior on overlflow

Tags: c

I'm looking at a legacy embedded project with the C30 compiler from microchip for a 16bit MCU.  There is an expected case where the index wraps around from 0xFF which I thought would be pre-defined behavior.  However the following code always dumps me in `//sad :(` when I expect to end up in happy.

```
unsigned char index = 0xFF;
unsigned char check = 0x02;

if(check == index +3){
    //happy!
}else{
    //sad :(
}
```

Now if I specifically cast it to an `unsigned char`:

```
unsigned char index = 0xFF;
unsigned char check = 0x02;

if(check == (unsigned char) index +3){
    //happy!
}else{
    //sad :(
}
```

It works and I end up in `//happy!` So what have I missed? Is this just compiler dependent behavior?

Comment: Try `(unsigned char)(index + 3)`. I'll leave finding out _why_ as a subsidiary task to you. And note the second example should also **not** work.

Comment: Hi Olaf, I did try that I show it in my second example.  I'm just not sure why it worked.  I get that it overflows, but I expect it to overflow to 0x02

Comment: Time to learn using the debugger. Or just have a look at the Assembler code, this is an excellent starter.

Comment: OK I can use the debugger just fine thanks...  My question is why would the compiler do this. Is it defined behavior in C99, etc.

Comment: C standard is C11, not C99. Anyway, iirc, it has been defined behaviour since K&R-1 and definitively C89.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The cause are *integer promotions*.

Whenever an integer type could be represented by an `int` in an expression the type is promoted to `int`.

In the first case `index` is promoted to type int, then the addition happens and you get the value 258, which does not equal to 2.

In the second case the expression should be `(unsigned char)( index +3 )` since the cast has precedence but perhaps the compiler is smart enough to figure it out.

Comment: Ah perfect thank you that lead me to the explanation.